# Regular expression does not work in javascript with keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate some inputs by regular expressions using the Keypress event to prevent some characters.

I have this function:

```
function validateRegularExpression(event, expression) {
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

And if I call it with the next code works fine:

```
$("#input").keypress(function (e) {
    return validateRegularExpression(e, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
});
```

But if I call it with other expression like **"^\d{0,3}(.\d)?$"** doesn't work.

Even I've changed the escape character by double **\\**

I need to use this function that way because I have a lot of input that I need to validate with regular expressions, so What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: How does it "not work" does it crash? Does it not-validate? A couple console.log() of your values would be great. A snippet event better

Comment: You are testing just the single character  not the full field value. Is this really what you mean?

Comment: With this regexp **"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"** returns **true** and in the input appears the character that I introduce, but with other regexp like **"^\d{0,3}(.\d)?$"** return **false** and the character does not appear in the input.

Comment: @HBP Yes, I think my function is testing only the character that I am introducing, how can I test the whole text in the input?

Comment: `this.value` will give you the current value of the input field, but be aware that your regexp cannot test for characters not yet entered (obviously)

Comment: But I validate this in a function which is in other part of the code, so am I call **this.value** from there?

Answer (score 0):

You're testing two different things. The regex that works is properly testing against that single character, while the second one seems geared toward testing against a full string. In testing, however, it does appear to work properly when fully escaped, maybe you didn't get both of the `\d`

`"^\\d{0,3}(.\\d)?$"`

If you are looking to test the full value of the input, you should be testing against this `var str = e.target.value;`

Comment: I've tried with double escape character like you mentioned. I introduce a number and the character appears, but when I put a point(**.**) character my function returns **false** and the character does not appear

Comment: Right, that's the other part of what I was saying. You're testing against the single value of that one input character that's being put in. If you want to check against the whole input value, you need `e.target.value` which will give you the full contents of the input instead of just the last character typed. Also, `.` matches anything, that needs to be escaped to `\.` to correctly match a period. Ideally, your expression should probably look something like `"^\\d{0,3}(\\.\\d?)?$"`. The `\\d` needs a `?` after it, because otherwise it won't let you type the `.` with nothing after it

Comment: The best approach is probably a combination. So on keydown, you're looking for `"[\\d\\.]"` which will make sure only digits or decimals are being typed. Then, afterward, you can use your `"^\\d{0,3}(\.\\d)?$"` regex to make sure the value is ok on submit

Comment: I did that you said, and now the function allows me introduce the **point** but I can  put **11.1.1.1** and returns true. I put a console.log() to look what is the value of **var str** and prints the message but without the last character I introduced and the **point** character doesn't print neither